# Хорошые книги, учебные материалы по веб-дизайну

Tags: веб-дизайн

Подскажите пожалуйста книги, учебные материалы по веб-дизайну. Интересуют: адаптивный дизайн, дизайн для мобильных устройств, типографика, цвет, правильные подходы проектирования со сторону юзабилити.

Не являюсь дизайнером, но необходимо понимание основ.

Comment: [Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию. Для списков литературы выделены особые поддерживаемые сообществом вопросы. Вместо того, чтобы задавать новый вопрос, найдите уже существующий в вопросе-указателе. Также список литературы и других ресурсов часто можно найти в описаниях меток по соответствующим темам.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию запрещены.

Comment: @Alex а нету каноничного ответа по книгам на данную тематику? надо значит создать, чтоб можно было направлять туда

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не нашел через поиск, постараюсь сделать на днях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Паттерны проектирования от ebay](https://www.gitbook.com/book/ebay/mindpatterns/details) - Эта книга помогает веб-разработчикам создавать доступные коммерчесие сайты и компоненты.

[Интерфейс. Основы проектирования взаимодействия. 4-е изд.](https://book24.ru/product/interfeys-osnovy-proektirovaniya-vzaimodeystviya-4-e-izd-657279/?fromreadru=y&utm_source=readru&ELEMENT_CODE=interfeys-osnovy-proektirovaniya-vzaimodeystviya-4-e-izd&ELEMENT_ID=657279) - Эта книга посвящена проектированию взаимодействия — практике проектирования интерактивных цифровых продуктов, сред, систем и сервисов